# POCO over DataTable

Tags: .net, orm, datatable

Most of the business logic is in StoredProcedures for us (this was required as there are multiple services/applications are using the same DB structure). So in order for the framework to be generic we chose DataTable. The data returned from the stored procedure is displayed in a grid and only 2 columns are editable and will be updated back to the DB.

We would like to switchover to simple objects. Are there any suggestions. We want to keep the generic approach. Frankly I haven't delved into any of the ORM tools.

We are on .Net 3.5.

To put it simple: How can I use objects where in I have to display data where the stored procedure returns different schema for different input params?

Comment: You're missing a "?" in your post, a sign that maybe something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

We have a database with a bunch of stored procs.  We're using petapoco for some of our data access, and straight ADO.NET for others.  It's really because we're in the process of moving to petapoco.